# M2: no_NO not recognised despite installed via community engineering lang pack

Tags: magento2, localisation

```
bin/magento info:language:list
```

This return `nb_NO` and `nn_NO` for Norwegian, however no_NO does not exist.
I can see some packages having the no_NO language file though (Stripe, Mageplaza).

I tried to installed the Crowdin language pack for Norwegian via composer as suggested by Crowdin (they don't have a nb_NO or nn_NO branch):

```
composer require community-engineering/language-no_no
```

Then I get the following error when running `setup:upgrade`

> no_NO argument has invalid value, please run info:language:list for
>   list of available locales

So of course my website does not translate to Norwegian.

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no_NO is outdated and should be replaced by nn_NO and/or nb_NO. This has allready been done in Magento2, but the community-engineering language pack just need to catch up and replace it aswell.

I have reached out the the Community Engineering project about this, as I have faced the same issue.